# how to ring all agents at same time with twillio flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working on building a call center using Twilio.

i want to do all available agents ring at the same time. Anyone can pick and then other agents are moved to the next caller if available.

Answer (score 0):

See below,

TaskRouter now dials only one worker for multi-reservation
https://www.twilio.com/changelog/taskrouter-now-dials-only-one-worker-multi-reservation

Answer (score 0):

You can dial multiple numbers or client to ring all agents.
You can refer below xml document.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial action="/handleDialStatus.php" method="GET">
    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```